# Bootstrap Datepicker and Disable C#/JSON array of dates,

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list of dates that I want to disable in my [bootstrap date picker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html).  I cannot get the datesDisabled function to work with the array of dates returned from JSON.  It does work with a hard coded array of dates.

Is there something that I need to do format the dates returned from JSON in order to get it to work?

Query:

```
var DatesBooked= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Calendar.Where(x =>  x.CalLocation != "OFF")).Select(x => x.CalDate).Distinct().ToList());
```

In my view:

```
@Html.TextBox("AddedDates", null, new { @class = "form-control small", @Value = ViewBag.SelDate, autocomplete = "off" })

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var unavailableDates= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DatesBooked));

     $input = $("#AddedDates");
                    $input.datepicker({
                        multidate: true,
                        multidateSeparator: ',',
                        datesDisabled: unavailableDates, 
                    });
    </script>
```

unavailableDates value

```
var unavailableDates = "[\"2016-05-01T00:00:00\",\"2016-05-02T00:00:00\",\"2016-05-03T00:00:00\",\"2016-06-24T00:00:00\",\"2016-06-25T00:00:00\"]"
```

If I hardcode thisfor unavailableDates, everything works fine.

```
var unavailableDates = ["05/25/2016", "05/26/2016"]
```

How do I need to format the dates in order to get this to work?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Well after many attempts and more research, I was able to solve this by doing the following:

I reformatted the date using C#:

```
var checkdates = db.Calendar.Where(x => x.CalLocation != "OFF")).Select(x => x.CalDate).Distinct().ToList()

var DatesBooked= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(checkdates, Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" });
```

Then in the view, I stripped the "\" characters returned by JSON and created an array:

```
var unavailableDates = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DatesBooked));
        var formatDates = unavailableDates.replace(/\\/g, "");
        var trimDate = formatDates.slice(1, -1);  // to remove " at beginning and end
        var finalDates = JSON.parse("[" + trimDate + "]");
        $input = $("#AddedDates");
        $input.datepicker({
            multidate: true,
            multidateSeparator: ',',
            datesDisabled: finalDates,
            todayHighlight: true
    });
```